# Glob Sync Pattern on multiple directories

Tags: javascript, regex, glob

I am trying to achieve a `glob` sync pattern that allows me to meet the following criteria, but unfortunately, im having a hard time working out why the pattern isn't working.

**Glob Pattern**

`glob.sync("./src/handlebar/{a, b, c, d}/**/*.hbs")`

**File Path Patterns**

```
src/handlebar/b/a/header.hbs
src/handlebar/b/header.hbs
src/handlebar/a/head.hbs [MATCH]
src/handlebar/a/foot.hbs [MATCH]
src/handlebar/c/a/something.hbs
src/handlebar/d/a/button.hbs
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Spaces are the problem, try:

```
glob.sync("./src/handlebar/{a,b,c,d}/**/*.hbs")
```